# Jupyter Notebook Suddenly Very Slow after Plotly install

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, plotly

> ### **Jupyter Notebook suddenly much slower than before**

- Pip installed Plotly 4.1.0
- Imported plotly.express within Jnotebook
- Suddenly even the *smallest tasks* take much longer to complete in Jupyter Notebook, when everything was working just fine immediately prior to download/import of plotly.express
- No actual error codes, just running **MUCH** slower than before

> I believe something happened when I downloaded Plotly(?)

- Took anything relating to Plotly or Plotly.express out of my notebook, still runs slower than before

> Installation

Ran these two lines, as per instruction of Plotly.

```
pip install plotly==4.1.0
pip install "notebook>=5.3" "ipywidgets>=7.2"
```

The second one returned "Requirement already satisfied" for every instance, so it must have been the plotly one, right?

currently running python 3.7.3 according to "python --version"

currently running jupyter 4.4.0 according to "jupyter --version"

Comment: Looked at other questions with issues regarding Jupyter. As I receive no actual error codes, and my cells do actually run (just much slower), so far no questions seem to be of any help.

Comment: What happens if you `pip uninstall plotly`?

Comment: Ended up being an issue with my magic command '%matplotlib'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## It was some conflict between pltoly and the magic command I had for matplot (%matplotlib).

- Just removed the magic command and restarted the kernel. Seems to work just fine now.

Comment: That seems really odd. I’ll look into it